# Three.js and GLSL - Kaleidoscope shader

Tags: glsl, webgl, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm starting and experimenting with GLSL and WebGL. Using Three.js r52.

I have a simple plane geom mesh with a Shader material.

I'm already passing a texture as uniform property, and I was able to manipulate it in different ways.

But, when I try to experiment the shaders from Shader Toy, more specifically this one http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/?p=Kaleidoscope , doesn't work the same way.

I think has something to do with positions.

Anyone have a clue about what could be the problem?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have this: http://bit.ly/TyA7EJ

I'm using coffee, so all the code is compiled in app.js. But maybe you can understand the problem just checking the final result.

Thank you very much.